# Python, list with regular gaps

Tags: python, list

I want to create a python list with regular gaps. I have a general idea of how I can do it, but is there a short way to do it or an inbuilt function to do this.

Suppose I want to create a list from 1 to 200, with gaps of 50. The list would be [1,..,50,101,..,150], i.e the sequence from 51 to 100 and 151 to 200 is not in the list.

```
def create_list_step(start,end,step):
     result = []
     current = start
     while current < end:
          smallinterval = current + step
          result = result + list(range(current, smallinterval))
          current = smallinterval + step
    return result
```

Comment: probably your are looking for `range`. For example: `list(range(1, 25, 2))` *(PS: Looks like your example in question is flawed as it doesn't contain equal interval)*

Comment: Take a look at [\[Python\]: range\(start, stop\[, step\]\)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) (you might have to combine).

Comment: giving OP benefit of the doubt, he may looking for an extendible / generic function. this is not an unreasonable thing to desire.

Comment: @MrT My bad, my question was badly phrased. I have updated my question. I was wondering if there was an in-built python function to do this. I tried to search online and the documentation, but I couldn't really find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to define a function which skips the gaps for you.

```
from itertools import chain

def gappy(start, rng, n):
    return chain(*(list(range(2*i*rng+1, (2*i+1)*rng+1)) for i in range(n)))

list(gappy(1, 50, 3))

# [1, 2, 3, ..., 48, 49, 50, 101, 102, 103, ...,
#  148, 149, 150, 201, 202, 203, ..., 248, 249, 250]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a built in function for that, but this can be easily done using concatenation of `range`s:

```
final = list(range(1, 51)) + list(range(101, 151))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm sorry that my question was badly phrased and I didn't provide enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions:

```
start = 5
stop = 17
gap = 3

a = [x for x in range(start, stop + 1) if ((x - start) // gap) % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one-liner that should do it:

```
[i for i in range(200) if (i-1)/50%2==0] #Python 2.x
[i for i in range(200) if (i-1)//50%2==0] #Python 3.x
```